# Python color fill not working when function is called

Tags: python, function, colors

Could use help understanding why the program doesn't fill any color when I call the parrallelogram function. I'm running Python v3. Here is my code.

```
    import turtle

    d_length = eval(input("Enter inside length of parallelogram: "))
    s = d_length / 2 * math.cos(math.pi / 4)
    parallelogramColor = turtle.fillcolor(" ")

    def parallelogram(s, parallelogramColor):
        for i in range(1):
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.forward(s)
            turtle.left(45)
            turtle.forward(s)
            turtle.left(135)
            turtle.forward(s)
            turtle.left(45)
            turtle.forward(s)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.end_fill()

    parallelogram(s, "brown")
```

Comment: Where do you use `parallelogramColor`?

Comment: Still very new coding but I thought I only needed to set parallelogramColor to variable turtle.fillcolor in order to use it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

[`fillcolor()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/turtle.html#turtle.fillcolor)'s documentation says

> If turtleshape is a polygon, the interior of that polygon is drawn with the newly set fillcolor.

So, the color of the *turtle* itself is changed not that of the shape drawn by it.

Use [`color()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/turtle.html#turtle.color) instead. As its documentation says, to

> Return or set pencolor and fillcolor

So, you could change your function to

```
def parallelogram(s, parallelogramColor):
    turtle.color(parallelogramColor)

    turtle.color(parallelogramColor)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(s)
    turtle.left(45)
    turtle.forward(s)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.forward(s)
    turtle.left(45)
    turtle.forward(s)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

You could remove that loop since there is only a single iteration.

Comment: Thanks J...S, for your help.  I was able to see that my fillcolor () and color() arguments where not formatted correctly.  Turns out all I needed to do was set the fillcolor locally within the function like so:   turtle.fillcolor(parallelogramColor).  This allowed the turtle to retain its default black outline with a new fill color as needed.